# Is it possible to have connection to multiple clusters via django-cassandra-engine?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, cassandra

I'm using django-cassandra-engine python library to use cassandra database in django. I wanted to know is there a way to have connection to multiple cassandra clusters and specify connection for cqlengine models.

Answer (score 2):

CqlEngine [supports](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/cqlengine/connections.html) registration of the multiple connections to different servers & switching between them.  Registration of new connection happens by creating session explicitly, and the registering it with `connection.register_connection`:

```
session = Cluster(['127.0.0.1']).connect()
connection.register_connection('connection1', session=session)
```

and then switching between them:

```
connection.set_default_connection('connection1')
```

I believe (but didn't check) that it should work with django-cassandra-engine...